# Get data from a web server response

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS app I'm using a web server. When I ask to the web server some information it respond me with this (and the type of this information is `id`):

```
(
        {
        "category_ids" =         (
            3
        );
        name = "Eau de Toilet";
        "product_id" = 1;
        set = 4;
        sku = "EAU_DE_TOILET_1";
        type = simple;
        "website_ids" =         (
            1
        );
    }
)
```

Now I will extract information from this, but how I can do that? I tried by using the instruction `objectForKey:`, but it gives to me an error. I tried to insert it to a NSArray but doesn't work. Can anyone help me to solve tho issue?

Comment: Try to populate an NSDictionary with the data

Comment: Yeah but how? Can you write me a code snippet to selve that?

Comment: @lucgian841 might help if you tell us what format this data is?

Comment: eh it's that the problem, indeed the methods who's getting me this data returns data type `id`. The web server documentation says that the response of my call should be an array. I'm trying to emulate that request by using a Chrome extension, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Can you cast it as an Array?

Comment: Yes, but you need to know how the data is formatted (JSON, XML, etc) in order to help you parse the document easily.

Comment: This looks neither like JSON nor XML

Comment: @NinjaLikesCheez: I know that, take a look at [this documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.list.html), you can see that the API I'm calling returns an array

Comment: @MrBr That wasn't my point.

Comment: @lucgian841, right, the webservice returns a SOAP array, so is this data already serialised? If so David H just answered your question :)

Comment: @NinjaLikesCheez: solved thank you for the suggestion. If you are interested how I solved just look to the answer of David H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is an array with one object, a dictionary, in it:

```
NSArray *array = ... // your data
NSDictionary *d = [array firstObject];
NSString *s = d[@"name"];
```